# How do I declare global reusable function in Nuxt with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js

I want to have some functions like showError, showNotice, showSuccess available globally.

I followed some tutorial and ended up doing this:

1. Create global.d.ts file with content:

   ```
   declare global {
     const showSuccess: Toast;
     const showWarning: Toast;
     const showNotice: Toast;
     const question: QuestionFunction;
   }
   ```
2. Added following code inside my Notification.ts

   ```
   const notificationPlugin: Plugin = function ({}, inject: Function)     {
     inject('showSuccess', showSuccess);
     inject('showError', showError);
     inject('showWarning', showWarning);
     inject('showInfo', showInfo);
     inject('confirm', confirm);
   };

   export default notificationPlugin;

   const _global = (global | window) as any;
   _global.showSuccess = showSuccess;
   ```

But, its not working for me. Webstorm does shows the function definition when I hover over the function. But, Nuxt throws error, that showSuccess is not defined.

Update: Now I've got it to work by making following changes in Notification.ts file

```
declare global {
  function showSuccess<T>(message: string | toastOption, options?: messageOption): void;
  function showError<T>(message: string | toastOption, options?: messageOption): void;
  function showInfo<T>(message: string | toastOption, options?: messageOption): void;
  function showWarning<T>(message: string | toastOption, options?: messageOption): void;
  function confirm<T>(message: string, questionOption?: Partial<QuestionOption>): Promise<boolean>;
}
```

Now,I can build app without any errors. But, webstorm still shows undefined function error.

Comment: As an alternative, you could define and export your functions from an external `.ts` file, and import the function when you need it.

Comment: I can't. I 'm using iziToast for showing notification, which doesn't support SSR. So, importing `showSuccess` throws me 'document is not defined' error.

Comment: You can create a plugin too. Just create the function in that plugin and inject the same and it will be available.

Comment: @ATULKUMARSINGH I did that and I can use `this.$showSuccess` inside component. But, I want to be able to use these functions globally, without imorting them. eg. in my model class, my axios interceptors, requests class etc.

Comment: Where have you imported the file? You just need to mention the newly created plugin in the file nuxt.config.js under the parameter named "plugin". Nothing needs to be imported at all.

Comment: @ATULKUMARSINGH, million thanks for your interest. I am using plugin to inject these functions globally, which is working for me. What I am saying is, I need a way to use these functions outside nuxt js context as well. Currently only way I could see this possible is using prototype to inject these functions in required classes. eg. `Model.prototype.$showSucces` or `Request.prototype.$showSuccess`. I was hoping there was some nicer way to do this and get auto completion as well.